# Message from a telegram bot without a command(python)

Tags: python, command, telegram, telegram-bot, message

I want to send a Message(call a function) every day at a given Time. Sadly this is not possible with message.reply_text('Test'). Is there any way i can do this? I could not find anything.

This is my current code:

```
import telegram.ext
from telegram.ext import CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters
import schedule
import time

API_KEY = 'XXXXXXXXXXX'   
updater = telegram.ext.Updater(API_KEY)
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher


def start(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text('Welcome!')


# problem:
def Test(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text('Works!!!')


# running special functions every Day at a given Time
schedule.every().day.at("10:00").do(Test)


while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)


def main():
    # add handlers for start and help commands
    dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))


    # start your bot
    updater.start_polling()
    # run the bot until Ctrl-C
    updater.idle()
```

The schedule part works, I just don`t know how to send this Message.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update object, inside of the message field, has the ***from*** field which is a [User Telegram object](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#user) containing the user's ID.

Once you have the user's ID, you can use the **[sendMessage](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage)** method in order to reply him easily.

To conclude, instead of:

```
update.message.reply_text('Welcome!')
```

You could do like so:

```
user_id = update.message.from.id
updater.sendmessage(chat_id=user_id, text="Welcome!")
```

Comment: Hey @Istorn, I copied code from [echobot.py](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/echobot.py) and test the updater.sendmessage(chat_id=user_id, text="Welcome!")

it returns `'Updater' object has no attribute 'sendmessage'`, seems like the updater has no `.sendmessage()` method in it. Is there any alternative for sending a message without calling a callback? Thanks

Comment: @EkkyArmandi in that case would be better to reading their documentation: Stack Overflow has to be considered a place to share a solution to a given problem. In your case I attempted to give you a walkthrough in relation to the Telegram's API Bot official documentation. My advice, is to keep going and reading the documentation in relation with.